# SharePoint 2013 Dynamic Data on all pages

Tags: sharepoint, user-controls, web-parts

If I have a requirement of displaying the a content on all the pages inside a header, Whats the best way to do that in an SharePoint 2013?

I am working on a master page that will be using the design manager and there is possibility of using the same master page in the SharePoint online too. The reason why I want to know what is the best way, when I use this same master page in SharePoint online I would like avoid redoing that entire coding for getting a dynamic data from the web service.

Several ways that I have been planning is below
 - User control method
 - Web part method, but requires server side coding which I doubt can used in online version

This is a complete dynamic data that will be retrieved by a web service and no internal SharePoint data be used.

Thanks for reading
Deepak

Comment: If its possible to consume web-service using jQuery/Ajax call you can go with that , Or else if you want to use c#,  might need to go with provider hosted app feature (sharepoint 2013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If its possible to consume web-service using jQuery/Ajax call you can go with that
2. Or else if you want to use c#, might need to go with provider hosted app feature (sharepoint 2013)
3. You can create a Visual Web Part for SharePoint 2013 Online.

Your web part will be contained in a Sandbox Solution which you will develop locally. Once development is complete you will upload the Solution Package created by Visual Studio to SharePoint Online.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80164/create-visual-webpart-for-sharepoint-online

http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/sharepoint-online-2013-web-part-deployment

Comment: Thanks for answers Vinayak. I went with using the Visual Web Part solution. Its getting confusing to choose the right approach with a maintainable code base with multiple options. I hate that part where I need to create multiple apps to support different functionality. Simple reason being that I can't have ten app projects in my one Visual Studio solution to support various business cases however simple it is.

Comment: Each option that you have said has advantages, but each has its own major disadvantages that makes it simply stick to out of box and stop working with other service internal to a company.